# How do I use numix-gtk-dark-theme?

Tags: gnome, themes, numix

according to [numix-gtk-dark-theme github](https://github.com/numixproject/numix-gtk-theme-dark) it's clear that this project is open source, so i was wondering why some people say that it's not? is it a paid theme?

in addition ,i want to know how to use this theme?

Comment: Please provide sources of information. This can be seen as spam trying to promote the theme. Have you tried finding the author and asking for help?

Answer (score 3):

It's not.

1. Download its project from [Github](https://github.com/numixproject/numix-gtk-theme-dark)
2. Extract the zip file to the themes directory i.e. `/usr/share/themes/`
3. (For GNOME users) run the following commands:

   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "Numix Dark"
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme "Numix Dark"

Now go to **Tweaks > Appearance > Themes(tab), Applications** choose *numix-gtk-theme-dark-master*

Comment: Hmmm... "Unlike our main theme which support up to GTK 3.24, this theme is still stuck at 3.14 and below."